# MemoryStream and constructing an array of bytes

Tags: delphi, memorystream

I am using a MemoryStream to construct an array of bytes i need to send to a server.I have thre questions:

1) Is there a better way to construct an array of bytes than this ?

2) Why this pice of code writes bogus in my memory stream ?

```
var
  serial : word;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
const
  somebytes : array [0..1] of byte = ($72,$72);
...
begin
      MS := TMemoryStream.Create();
      try
      MS.Write(somebytes[0],2);
      serial := $3E6C;
      MS.Write(serial,2);
      finally
      MS.Free;
end;
```

Using the debugger i see that in the stream is added the value $6F32 instead of $3E6C.

3) If i call

```
MS.Position := 2;
```

and then i access PByte(MS.Memory)^ why do i get the first byte in the stream instead of the third?

Comment: To read a byte at a specific position, use `MS.Read(SomeByte,1)` after setting the position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a better way to construct an array of bytes than this?

That's a perfectly reasonable way to do it, in my view.

---

> I see that in the stream is added the value $6F32 instead of $3E6C.

Check again. The correct values are in fact added. But beware of the traps of little endian data types. The 4 bytes added to your stream, in order, are: $72, $72, $6C, $3E.

---

> Why do I get the first byte in the stream instead of the third?

Because the `Memory` property always refers to the beginning of the stream. It does not take account of the stream's current position.

Comment: You can always get the pointer as a PByte and then do P := Stream.Memory; Inc( P, Stream.Position ); to get the correct pointer